# How to mutate field in struct within a pointer?

Tags: pointers, struct, rust

If I have a variable of type `P<SomeStruct>` (owned, or a mutable reference), is it possible to mutate a field on that struct, without returning a new pointer? I've been trying something like this:

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]

extern crate syntax;

use syntax::ptr::P;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Baz {
    id: String,
}

#[test]
fn foo() {
    let mut pointer = P(Baz { id: "blah".to_string() });
    bar(&mut pointer);
}

fn bar(x: &mut P<Baz>) {
    x.id = "bing".to_string()
}
```

but of course that fails with:

```
error: cannot assign to immutable field
   --> src/lib.rs:116:5
    |
116 |     x.id = "bing".to_string()
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow immutable field
```

Is there any way to mutate a field on a struct within a smart pointer?

Playground URL: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5675bc2ef4297fe691204a69ffc19461&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Comment: This is not reproducible. Consider writing an example in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) that shows this exact compilation error.

Comment: @E_net4, I've added the necessary imports and feature flags, and a link to rust playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to mutate a field on a struct within a smart pointer?

Sure, here's an example using `Box` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eca576de8cc0b16828f72e16e1dac53d&version=nightly&backtrace=0)):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Baz {
    id: String,
}

#[test]
fn foo() {
    let mut pointer = Box::new(Baz { id: "blah".to_string() });
    bar(&mut pointer);
}

fn bar(x: &mut Box<Baz>) {
    x.id = "bing".to_string()
}
```

But you seem to be trying to do that with `syntax::ptr::P`, which self-describes as a [**frozen** owned smart pointer](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ptr/index.html):

> - **Immutability**: `P<T>` disallows mutating its inner `T`, unlike `Box<T>` [...]

To be more specific, `P<T>` implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), but not [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), so you can't get a `&mut T` out of a `&mut P<T>` by dereferencing it.